# Why return the copy of the array?

Tags: java, solr, dataimporthandler

I am reading the source code of dataimporthandler component of solr. I meet a question

```
  private List<String> readBySplit(String splitBy, String value) {
    String[] vals = value.split(splitBy);
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.addAll(Arrays.asList(vals));
    return l;
  }
```

↑ listing 1 (method from RegexTransformer class)

```
  private List<String> readBySplit(String splitBy, String value) {
    String[] vals = value.split(splitBy);
    return Arrays.asList(vals);
  }
```

↑ listing 2 (I think the above method should be)

Can anyone tell me what the significant difference between above two code listings? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()` `Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.`

That's from javadoc. So if you want a dynamic sized list, you need first code.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList()` returns fixed-sized list which is unmodified list. You can not perform add/remove operation on it, on doing so will throw `Exception` `UnsupportedOperationException`.

So your first method is appropriate if you want to do some operation with the list

Comment: he still can modify the list, just not change size

Comment: Modification means add/remove. you cant do add/remove in that list

Comment: try: `  String[] a = { "1", "2", "3"};
  List<String> b = Arrays.asList(a);
  b.set(1,"haha");
  System.out.println(b);`

Comment: This is not adding new element/removal. I mentioned about addition and removal only

Comment: You said "which is unmodified list" as well you said "Modification means add/remove". Anyways, whatever initial intention of wording was, I think it is now clear what can and what cannot be done with the this kind of list.

Answer (score 0):

You cant add anything in the list return by code 2 because it returns fixed size list.You will get **"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
"** but you can add in the list return by code 1.